# Plone addon dynamic url

Tags: python, plone

i am developing an addon on plone. I need to add some dynamic url with dynamic value like `harvest/jobs/[jobid]/[detailid]`

In here **job id** and **detail id** can be dynamic.
 I need to point them on one view.

Please help me to point these dynamic value to one view. I need to use it in plone standalone.

please also let me know **if there is any url rewrite (like apache)** in plone standalone.

Comment: Dig into traversing of zope. You may do a little research and ask a specific question!

Comment: If `jobs` is your view, you should be able to get jobid and detailid from the request's `TraversalRequestNameStack`, but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking?

Comment: Needs to be like that or can it be like ``harvest/jobs?jobid=XX&detailid=YY``? That would make things far more easier

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.routes/1.1a2 might be of some use to you.

Or as the comments suggest, use normal objects and traversal.